# Drip irrigation system

Tags: identification, irrigation, drip-system

I recently visited an urban farm and was intrigued with their irrigation system. I haven't been able to find the components online either because they built it from scratch or I'm using the wrong terms. Unfortunately I didn't take a picture of the set up.

The main line is pvc pipe with holes rather than polyethylene pipe and it had 1/4" tubes coming from the pvc directly to each individual pot. Water drips out in drops rather than as a stream.

Anyone has an idea what this system is called or where to get the components?

Answer (score 3):

Without a photo, I'm only taking a stab at describing what I think you saw.  There are many different names for this product, and it's made by at least Rainbird, Toro, and Netafim (probably others), but the larger tubing is probably call [drip line](http://www.rainbird.com/landscape/products/dripline/XFS.htm)) (url was chosen for the photo rather than a recommendation of a specific product).  It usually comes a bunch of layouts with 2 variables - rate of flow (in gallons per hour), and distance.

If you haven't worked with low flow irrigation before there are some good manuals out there, or I can try to summarize for you if you'd like.

Comment: It's similar to this https://blueearthsustainable.com/drip-systems/american-hydroponics-drip-system-add-on-2x4-ah91065 I found it while looking up hydroponic systems. They may have adapted to use with mixed hydroponic and irrigation systems. The urban farm has a short week schedule. I won't be able to find out until Tuesday.

Comment: Hydroponics isn't my area of expertise, sorry.  You could do the same thing with some blank tubing and barbed fitting, but it might not be cost effective as I think you can only by roles of 50 feet of blank tubing.

Comment: @MenachemEliyahu - Where you ever able to find out more?